# Rails tempfile directory + extension and routing

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes, temporary-files

I want to write images to the tmp directory and then serve them.  However, when I use the format `file = Tempfile.new(["picture", ".jpeg"])` the file doesn't get created properly.  Alternatively, if I use `file = Tempfile.new(Rails.root.to_s + "/tmp/picture.jpeg")` we don't get the jpeg extension.

Also, in the latter case, I get the error `ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home/saasbook/highlandsappfinal/tmp/picture20130701-2349-1vug8pz")`  How do I create a route to serve images from the tempfile directory?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Answer (score -1):

You need to use Rack middleware for this
in `config.ru`

```
use Rack::Static, :urls => ['/carrierwave'], :root => 'tmp'
```

example from my carrierwave configuration

Comment: Thanks, will try this out now and get back to this page once I have some results.

Comment: How do I enforce the jpeg extension but still get it to write to the right place?

Comment: I don't understand your question.

Comment: So for now, I added use Rack::Static, :urls => ["/tmp"], and I'm still getting "ActionController::RoutingError (No route matches [GET] "/home/saasbook/highlandsappfinal/tmp/picture20130708-1990-1fw377h")."  Any idea why?

Comment: How do you link to the photo?